# python naming convention for verb with adv/adj?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

Maybe this is not a valid question, but I could not find anything about this.

I defined a function to match keys in a `dict`, return value if a given key partially contained in any key:

```py
def partially_get(d: dict, key: str, default: Optional[Any] = None):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if key in k:
            return v
    return default
```

Is there any "proper" naming convention for this kind of function name?

Should I use "verb_adj", "verb_adv", "adj_verb", or "adv_verb"?

==============

UPDATE

As @August suggested, ends with a noun seems clearer.

`get_partially_matched_item` is too long, so I'll go with `partially_matched_item`.

Comment: "Lookup or default in" with your choice of handling spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with `patially_matched_item`. In general when you want to name a function which has no side-effects (only returns a result) it's a good idea to name it after the result it returns. Therefor you want a noun as the last word prefixed with adjectives which describe the result with sufficient precision in the given context. In the most general sense the result is an *item*. Since it matches a key it's a *matched item* and since it partially matches a key we end up with the name `partially_matched_item`.

Comment: Maybe you're right. "get" + "partial" sounds like getting a part from something, instead matching a part of a key. `partially_matched_item` feels more natural. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly subjective. But for consistency with built-in functions such as `getattr`, `isinstance`, etc I'd probably go with something like `get_partial`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

- `get_partial_key`
- `partial_name`